# How to send SQL data gain from a php script to a python script?

Tags: php, python, sql

I'm struggling with a question.
So I created a Neural Network, but now I want to put values from my database in it. It's important that the data from the database is collected by a php script (already created), and **has been send** to my python Neural Network script. How do I transfer multiple variables and even multiple rows from my database to a python script?

Comment: This question is simply too broad. There are many ways to interact with databases and transfer between PHP and Python scripts. Please make an effort on one way and return with specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to share data is via API. Prepare array containing multiple data you want to send then convert the data to JSON. On python, decode the JSON then take data out of it one by one. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Ok, let me know